# Extracting value of raster for specific points (with X and Y coord) and write to column in Attribute Table?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

[image]I have specific points in shp file  and list of rasters in the same coord system 
and want to extract   values from rasters for  each point 
and place these values in column in Attribute Table  of   shp  file of points.

Rasters are separate files.

Is it possible to go from vector to raster?

Shp file pf points:

```
infc = 'samplepoints1.shp'
```

code just a start:

```
import arcpy

infile = r"C:\Users\anna_pavlenko\Desktop\SILVER\biscuit_dnbr.tif"
#create raster object
ftc = arcpy.sa.Raster(infile)
#rows and columns
ftc.height 
ftc.width 
#cell size
cellSize = ftc.meanCellHeight
print 'The cell  size is ', cellSize, 'm'

rasterList = r"C:\Users\biscuit_dnbr.tif"
rstArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rasterList)

rows, cols = rstArray.shape
print "number of rows: " ,  rows
print "number of columns: ", cols

for rowNum in xrange(rows):
    for colNum in xrange(cols):
        value = rstArray.item(rowNum, colNum)
```

If I use

```
inRasterList = [["biscuit_dnbr.tif", "foothills_dnbr.tif", "dNBR1"] ,     ["biscuit_rdnbr.tif", "foothills_rdnbr.tif", "RdNBR1"],["silver_dnbr.tif", "pony_complex_dnbr.tif", "dNBR2"], ["silver_rdnbr.tif", "pony_complex_rdnbr.tif", "RdNBR2"]] 
#  ["foothills_dnbr.tif","dNBR1"], "foothills_rdnbr.tif", "RdNBR1"],
#  ["pony_complex_dnbr.tif", "dNBR2"], "pony_complex_rdnbr.tif", "RdNBR2"]]

ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(inPointFeatures, inRasterList, "NONE")
```

This  function  create  values  for 1 place (polygon) and extract value  for point inside this polygon only  and place them in columns:   "dNBR1", "dNBR2",  "RdNBR1", "RdNBR2".
     For another set of rasters  it create   0 -zeros for  first points and add new columns :  "dNBR1_1", "dNBR2_1",  "RdNBR1_1", "RdNBR2_"  each time.

Comment: There is a tool for this task sample sa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the spatial analyst extension or want to use Numpy, you can convert your x and y point coordinates to the row and column that is close to that point. The Extract Values tools have many more options, and produce slightly different results than those in the code below. I'm not advocating one method over another. I also don't know if this would be any faster.

```
import numpy as np
```

Get information about your raster file:

```
rast = arcpy.Raster(r"somePath")
desc = arcpy.Describe(rast)
```

Get the upper left corner of the raster and spatial reference system (you can ignore the spatial reference if all your points and rasters are the same).

```
ulx = desc.Extent.XMin
uly = desc.Extent.YMax
#Spatialrefernce
sr = desc.spatialReference
```

Convert the raster to a numpy array

```
rstArray  = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rast)
```

Access your Feature Class using an update cursor to add the value. I'm using the projectAs tool to make sure the point is in the same coordinate system as the raster. Calculate the row and col based on how far the point is from the upper left corner. This can very depending on rounding. Then pass this into your numpy array.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("NHDPoint",["SHAPE@","value"]) as uc:
    for row in uc:
        pnt = row[0].projectAs(sr)
        #assuming every point falls to the left and below uperleft corner
        deltaX = pnt.centroid.X - ulx
        deltaY = lly- pnt.centroid.Y
        arow = int(deltaY/rast.meanCellHeight)
        acol = int(deltaX/rast.meanCellWidth)
        row[1] = rstArray[arow,acol]
        uc.updateRow(row)
```

This code assumes that the points will fall to the right of upper left corner, and below it. It also just used the default rounding when converting the float to an integer.

Another option, which might be closer to what the Extract tools is to use a distance to the center of the cell from your points to determine which value to use.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by adding lly = desc.Extent.YMin as it was failing on deltaY = lly- pnt.centroid.Y

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tool [pointed out by HDunn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/189884/115), you can use [Extract Multi Values to Points](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-multi-values-to-points.htm) if you have many raster data with the same point shapefile. Here is another snippet from ArcGIS help.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env 
env.workspace = "c:/sapyexamples/data"
ExtractMultiValuesToPoints("observers.shp", [["elevation", "ELEV"], 
                           ["costraster", "COST"], ["flowdir", "DIR"]], "NONE")
```

Comment: This  function  create  values  for

Comment: The above function will update the original file and add fields for of raster names used, which means this tool modifies the input data. Make sure to have a copy of your original input shapefile as backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using ArcPy, You might as well use the `Extract Values to Points` [tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm) (assuming you have Spatial Analyst extension)

Here's the code snippet from ESRI's site

```
ExtractValuesToPoints("rec_sites.shp", "elevation",
                  "C:/sapyexamples/output/outValPnts","INTERPOLATE",
                  "VALUE_ONLY")
```

Iterate over your raster layers like you did and extract values to your point layer

Comment: This function place  output  value in separate  file   - the values in the attribute table of an output feature class.  I want in the same   file  of point  infc = 'samplepoints1.shp'   just to add new column in Attribute Table.